# Converse of Abel's test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am considering the converse of Abel's test. Suppose $\sum_{n}a_{n}b_{n}$ is convergent, $b_{n}$ is monotonic, bounded and positive, is $\sum_{n}a_{n}$ converge?

Comment: Say $a_n=b_n=\frac 1n$ or $a_n=1, b_n=\frac 1{n^2}$.

Comment: $a_n=n ,b_n=\frac 1{n^3}$

Comment: assume $b_n \to a >0$, then $1/b_n \to 1/a$ and is monotonic, positive and bounded so $\sum (a_nb_n)(1/b_n)=\sum a_n$ converges;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let, $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$. So $b_n$ is monotonic and bounded as $0<b_n \leq1$. Also $\sum_n a_n b_n$ is convergent but $\sum_n a_n$ is not convergent..